# how to change a image size in C#

Tags: c#, image, width

I have a image.
The image 's width is 100, and height is 150.
this 100 and 150 is Pixel units.
I want to change the height to 1280px, the width to 1280px

how to do it?

I know a class in c# is Image,but Image.width is not a pixel
how to convert it?

Comment: You want to the size change do it programmatically or once and done?

Comment: https://www.google.pl/search?q=c%23+image+resize

Comment: What do you meany by [Image.Width not a pixel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.width.aspx) ? Its unit is pixel as documented.

Comment: Do you need a new image with that size? Simplest method is to create a new bitmap with required size, a Graphics object to draw on that then to draw original image stretched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static Image resizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
{
   return (Image)(new Bitmap(imgToResize, size));
}

yourImage = resizeImage(yourImage, new Size(1280,1280));
```

You need to use a hight resolution image to get a good one when it is larger . from 100x150 to 1280x1280 the picture will be blurred

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have solved this problem